# Targeting Multiple DB Providers (one per installation)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm migrating an EF 6 application that currently uses SQL Server to optionally use MySQL instead. One or the other will be used for a particular deployment. Never a mix of both.

I'm running into trouble with EF migrations. I create the migration code targeting SQL Server then hand-edit the generated migration to apply a few MySQL-specific tweeks (e.g. using `mediumtext` instead of `varchar(max)` for select properties) when MYSQL is defined at compile time (`#if MYSQL`). When I then change the application configuration to target MySQL and either run `update-database` or just run the application, the application's database and all tables are created, but then an exception is thrown:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The underlying provider does not support the type 'nvarchar(max)'.'

Note the data type is SQL Server-specific, not MySQL. The exception is thrown from external code (presumably Entity Framework code), right after the following method is called:

```
string IMigrationMetadata.Id
{
    get { return "202004101817407_S_InitialMigration"; }
}
```

My working assumption is, the representation of the data model present in __MigrationHistory and in the .resx accompanying the migration code file encodes the SQL Server representation.

What strategy can I follow to use EF 6 and EF Migrations optionally with either SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: [Possible dupe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496960/ef6-codefirst-mysql-migrations-type-nvarcharmax-not-supported) However, do your strings have max lengths? The EF conventions will treat all strings as `nvarchar(max)` if not specifically mapped.

Comment: The other question is certainly similar and possibly a dupe. Most of my strings have max lengths, but some cannot (they hold open-ended text that can be quite long).